# stale NFS file handle on git after hard reboot on Google VM

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, server

after hard reboot, of my Google VM:

git pull error:

```
fatal: protocol error: unexpected 'Error running git: fork/exec /usr/bin/git-upload-pack: stale NFS file handle'
```

git push error:

```
fatal: protocol error: unexpected 'Error running git: fork/exec /usr/bin/git-receive-pack: stale NFS file handle'
```

What i can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to unmount the NFS file system and remount it. A hard reboot might also require a file system check **fsck** of the VM's file systems.

Note: the **umount** will probably report an error/warning as the system thinks the NFS file system is mounted when it is not.

Comment: As @John Hanley mentioned, unmounting the NFS file system and remounting it helps you fix the issue .This [document](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/mounting-fileshares#mounting_a_file_share_on_a_vm_instance) has detailed explanation on Mounting file shares on Compute Engine